# The import com.google.ads cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, admob

I have encountered a problem while I was adding ads to my app.  The problem is that when I import the ads, it gives me an error. The error is `The import com.google.ads cannot be resolved`.  I don't know how to resolve it.  I have checked the internet and banged my head on the wall for the past week.  Nothing is working.  Here's what I have:

[image: import error]

My Android SDK Manager:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

My JAR files:

[image: Libraries]

Order and Export:

[image: Order and Export]

Project Explorer:

[image: Project Explorer]

For my project build target in project.properties, it is `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17`

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to add something?  Any help regarding this problem is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.currencyconverter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the `zip` and not the `jar` in your eclipse build path. Unzip the zipped file, take the jar out of it and add it to your eclipse build path.

Comment: I'll accept the answer in seven minutes.  SO is not letting me do it for a brief period of time.